# Trouble getting all of the variables to work, once one is clicked

Tags: variables, actionscript

just a quick question. Basicaly, I'm making a simple game to accompany my murder mystery interactive website and I'm having some actionscript issues. The idea is that the user will be able to click on objects around the room, and recieive clue, find keys etc. One of the problems im having is when the user clicks the lamp, it brings up a box over the screen to resemble nighttime, however, when the screen reverts to normal, none of the other elements, i.e the book, are clickable - again, im sure this is a simple solution that I am just overlooking, here is the full code;

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


book.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getBook);
key.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getKey);
door.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoBedroom);
//paper.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getNote);
Lamp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,getDark);


var gotBook:Boolean = false;
var gotKey:Boolean = false;


key.visible = false;
NightTime.visible = false;

//function getNote(evt:MouseEvent):void{

        //report.gotoAndPlay(1);
    //}





function getKey(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    if(gotBook==false){
        key.visible = false;
    }else{
        key.visible = true;
    }
}

function gotoBedroom(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    if(gotKey==true){
       gotoAndStop("Bedroom");
    }else
    feedBackText.gotoAndPlay(1);

}

if(gotBook==true){
    book.visible = false;
    key.visible = true;
    }


function getBook(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    book.visible = false;
    key.visible = true;

}

function getDark(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    NightTime.gotoAndPlay(1);
    NightTime.visible = true;
}





stop()
```

any help in making all of the variables clickable at the same time would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, by calling getDark function you show NightTime box (or whatever it is) which cover the screen. I can't see function which is calling
NightTime.visible = false;
so i guess after you show it it's there all the time and overlap rest of screen.

If that's the reason, adding

```
    NightTime.mouseChildren = false;
    NightTime.mouseEnabled = false;
```

should solve the problem.